# Perl complication failed on "has ... => ..."

Tags: perl, mojolicious

Could anyone help explain the grammer about "has usage ...", "has description ..." in below cgi.pm?

```
package Mojolicious::Command::cgi;
use Mojo::Base 'Mojolicious::Command';

use Mojo::Server::CGI;
use Mojo::Util 'getopt';

has description => 'Start application with CGI';
has usage => sub { shift->extract_usage };

sub run {
  my ($self, @args) = @_;
  getopt \@args, nph => \(my $nph = 0);
  Mojo::Server::CGI->new(app => $self->app, nph => $nph)->run;
}

1;
```

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: I just can't understand "has" here. I thought it's a grammer issue and I had never seen it before.
D:\Source\GitHub\Mojolicious\tweetylicious>perl tweetylicious.pl
syntax error at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Mojolicious/Command/cgi.pm line 7, near "has description"
Compilation failed in require at (eval 289) line 1.

Comment: `has LIST` is just a sub call. Because the parens around the argument list has been omitted, the sub needs to have been declared before the call, thus the syntax error.

Comment: I rhink you can use a proto-type to declare run.  i.e. "sub run {}" on the line before your sub run is defined.

Answer (score 0):

See the [Mojo::Base documentation](https://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojo/Base).  The `has` function defines an attribute for the class.

In this case `Mojo::Command::cgi` has a `Mojolicious::Command` base class and the `description` attribute defaults to the string supplied, and the `usage` attribute will be initialized by calling the `extract_usage` method.